# Missing background of software center

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I newly installed ubuntu 20.04 and when I'm opening the software center or when I'm installing .deb file, the background of the window is missing. just buttons and texts.

here is some screenshots,

[image]

[image]

is this a bug or something wrong with my computer?

Comment: have you installed any themes or tried to edit theme files?

Comment: no nothing, just fresh installation